# Derivatives with ln Issues

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

[image]

I got 3x^2/x^3-7 but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Also I ran into this problem and haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the chain rule:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f^\prime(g(x))g^\prime(x)$$
Then, the tangent to the graph of $f(g(x))$ at $(x_1,y_1=f(g(x_1)))$ is
$$y-f(g(x_1))=f^\prime(g(x_1))g^\prime(x_1)(x-x_1)\\
\implies y=xf^\prime(g(x_1))g^\prime(x_1)-x_1f^\prime(g(x_1))g^\prime(x_1)+f(g(x_1))$$
Let me show you as an example the first one:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{3x^2}{x^3-7}\\
\implies \left.\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=2}=12\\
\implies y=xf^\prime(g(x_1))g^\prime(x_1)-x_1f^\prime(g(x_1))g^\prime(x_1)+f(g(x_1))\\
\implies y=12x-24$$

Comment: How do i do the first one? is the derivative right?

Comment: @user102817 See my edit.